# DLib - Why doesn't start_async() accept connections in a background thread?

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client, dlib

This is my first attempt with DLib. My goal is having a background server I can connect to with many client threads simultaneously. According to the documentation, `start_async()` should be the way to go with a concrete implementation of `dlib::server`, so this is how I set up my server.

```
class TestServer : public dlib::server
{
    private:
        void on_connect(dlib::connection& c)
        {
            cout << "Hi." << endl;
        }

    public:
        void start_server()
        {
            set_listening_ip("127.0.0.1");
            set_listening_port(4790);

            start_async();
        }
};
```

What follows is my `ServerMain.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TestServer ts;

    try
    {
        ts.start_server();
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is my `ClientMain.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        iosockstream stream("127.0.0.1:4790");

        cout << "CLIENT - Connected." << endl;
    }
    catch(exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Done." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After having started my server, any attempt to connect to it with a client results in an exception:

`unable to connect to '127.0.0.1:4790'`

Also, neither `lsof` nor `netstat` show any process listening on port `4790`.
**What am I doing wrong?**

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.5, compiled with `-std=c++11 -DDLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`.

Comment: Upvoted since you are showing us code and seem to have tried to solve this on your own. That's not saying that additional detail couldn't be added (like what OS etc)...

Comment: @JesperJuhl I put details about the OS on the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from dlib::server's documentation for start_async() it says

```
does NOT block.  That is, this function will return right away and
the server will run on a background thread until clear() or this
object's destructor is called (or until some kind of fatal error
occurs).
```

So your server program terminates immediately because you let the program end (you leave main()).  You have to do something to keep your program alive.  For example, call server's start() instead of start_async().

Comment: I tried using `start()` but it doesn't handle many connections simultaneously, but it does sequentially instead. According to my understanding of the `on_connect` method, it should start a new thread for every connection attempt, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: It does handle many connections simultaneously. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: I tried to put a greeting message and a `while(true);` immediately after in the `on_connect` function and then I made 10 clients attempt a connection with the server. They were served sequentially (oddly enough, each connection attempt had to wait exactly 10 seconds from the previous one before being served). I expected the greeting messages to be printed very fast one after the other but it didn't happen.

Comment: Well. You are testing it wrong somehow. The server is most definitely multi threaded. Each on_connect always happens in a separate thread.

Comment: I'll try to compile it on Linux and see what happens, but any idea on how I could test it better? Having a `while(true);` in the `on_connect` method sounded like the ultimate test to prove its multithreadedness.

Comment: You probably are messing up the clients.

Comment: The client's source code amounts to what I've posted above (plus the #include stuff). I make ten of them spawn by means of a super basic bash script (a for loop calling ./ClientMain ten times). Any idea? However, thanks for your replies.

Comment: Bash is not normally multi threaded. Maybe you aren't spawning multiple at once.

Comment: Argh, I would've never thought of that. Thank you very much! :)